# Android app giving I/InjectionManager? dispatchCreateOptionsMenu at screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am developing the app, when I am implementing the menu for my app, the I am hiding some menuitems from some screens and for this I am using this code :

```
@Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuItem search = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        search.setVisible(false);
        MenuItem create_opportunity = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_example);
        create_opportunity.setVisible(false);
        //this.invalidateOptionsMenu();
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

When I am uncommenting this invalidatinoptionsmenu line , it starts giving I/InjectionManager? dispatchCreateOptionsMenu continously in the logs of the app. May i know due to this the battery also can be consumed ?? , this logs I am getting in samsung mobiles only.

Appreciate your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on a similar issue with my own app. The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#options-menu) pretty much says it all:

> When an event occurs and you want to perform a menu update, you must call invalidateOptionsMenu() to request that the system call onPrepareOptionsMenu().

so calling invalidateOptionsMenu() from onPrepareOptionsMenu will create an infinite loop.